# How to play a clip only till an Out mark in Adobe Premiere?

Tags: premiere

In Adobe Premiere there are shortcut keys to play a clip right from the **In mark to Out mark**. Shortcut on a PC  is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

**However, how can I play a clip only till my Out mark?** Not my full selection from In to Out, but from an arbitrary point of a selection only to my Out mark? It should stop playing on my Out mark.

Answer (score 6):

To "Play from Playhead to Out Point":

- PC: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>
- Mac: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>

To "Play In to Out":

- PC: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>
- Mac: <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>

from: https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/keyboard-shortcuts.html

Comment: Wow, I didn't know this was possible, +1! I'll edit that into my answer as well

Comment: So there is no button for this? That's odd.

Comment: This is fantastic. Why this isn't more discoverable in the UI is beyond me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible. **Edit:** Turns out I was wrong. As Green mentions, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> will do exactly what you asked for. I'll leave the rest of my answer as alternatives to that.

Another option is the **Play Around** Shortcut, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, which will start playback a couple of seconds before your current timemarker position and stop a couple of seconds behind it. You can customize the **Preroll** and **Postroll seconds** under **Preferences** → **Playback**.